# Trouble using priority for user defined objects in c++

Tags: c++, huffman-code

So I need to write the Huffman Compression/Decompression for my school assignment and I'm having trouble using a priority queue to store the frequencies.

The two files that're giving me headaches are `HCNode.hpp` and `main.cpp`.  In the `HCNode.hpp` file I've overloaded `bool operator<(const HCNode& other)`  and in my `main.cpp` when I try to initialize a priority queue like this:

```
 priority_queue< HCNode, vector < HCNode >, less< HCNode> > freq;
```

The compiler throws me a bunch of errors

edit: here is one of the errors

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_queue.h:391:9:   instantiated from   ‘std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::priority_queue(const   _Compare&, const _Sequence&) [with _Tp = HCNode, _Sequence = std::vector, _Compare = std::less]’
>   compress.cpp:134:59:   instantiated from here

most of the errors seem to be from some sort of conflict with the library.

nevermind, fixed the problem, the teacher's code was incomplete.  Thank you to those who looked at this post though.

Comment: Don't you think you should post the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you posted is not the exact error message but the instantiating line which causes the actual error.

The most probable one causing error I think is because the comparator, which is operator< in this case, is not a const member function.

Check if it's a const member function.

Comment: Aha that was the exact cause of the error.  The teacher forgot the word 'const' at the end of the comparator in the file he gave us =\.